# for tomcat WTP(eclipse), what's the diff "publish" and "deploy"?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I just don't know what's the diff between those two action.

is there any official docs for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publish: Copy new changes from your project to an already deployed webapp.

Deploy: Copy the entire web project to Tomcat webapp dir.